# For HTML entities, should I use the named syntax or numerical syntax?

Tags: html, cross-browser, html-entities

For example, to represent `<`, is it better to use `&gt;` or `&#60;`, in terms of browser support?

[This page](http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/tagpages/text.htm#procon) makes the claim that one should avoid *name* syntax because "Not all browsers may support the newer entity names (160-191 range)". Does this advice still hold true for modern browsers (IE7+, FF3.5+, Safari, Chrome, Opera)?

(My IDE automatically converts special characters in HTML to entities, but only using the *named* syntax, so I'd like to use named entities for this reason, or find a utility that converts characters to their entities using *numerical* syntax.)

Comment: this doesn't directly answer your question but I use numerical because a lot of entities do not have a "name"

Answer (score 1):

These days, it doesn't really matter which you use. Named entities are easier to remember and cover 99% of what you'll ever use anyway.

Here's a handy guide and converter:

http://www.texaswebdevelopers.com/examples/xmlentities/xml_entities.asp